# SSH over VPN on Ubuntu Client Does not use Tun0

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openvpn

So, I set up my iptables rules on openvpn server (ubuntu) to allow ssh connections over `/dev/tun0` with range of ip.

output of pinky from server with both clients connected:

```
jimic@ridingthewave-vpn:~$ pinky
Login    Name                 TTY      Idle   When             Where
jimic                         pts/0         2017-07-25 11:19 173.48.##.##
jimic                         pts/1    00:02  2017-07-25 11:17 10.8.0.10
```

When I log in from my phone over openvpn you see the bottom, which is what I want.

When I log in from my home pc, also ubuntu, you see the top, which means ssh connection is not being routed through vpn. 
Both have open vpn client running, and desktop runs everything else through vpn, but not ssh. For some reason the home computer talks to the server directly only for ssh.

Any idea's on how I can fix this? Since it works fine from the phone I am certain it is an issue with the client desktop. Thanks for any ideas.

Couple updates:
ip route show on client machine gives:

> 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
>
> default via 192.168.1.1 dev wls1  proto static  metric 600
>
> 10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
>
> 10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6
>
> 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
>
> 138.1##.7.4# via 192.168.1.1 dev wls1
>
> 169.254.0.0/16 dev wls1  scope link  metric 1000
>
> 192.168.1.0/24 dev wls1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2
>
> metric 600

I think:

> vpn.ip.add.ress via 192.168.1.1 dev wls1

might be the problem, or it might be what makes openvpn work :)

Gonna have to learn more about route but any input about what that line does are appreciated.

Another update, running netstat -tupn on client has some interesting results:

> Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
>   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:55708          216.58.219.227:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:55770          216.58.219.227:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:44892          151.101.193.69:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:36648          198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:44678          216.58.219.238:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:139           127.0.0.1:58754         ESTABLISHED 19740/smbd
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:35248          172.217.3.106:443       ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp       28      0 127.0.0.1:58754         127.0.1.1:139           ESTABLISHED 19727/gvfsd-smb-bro
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:35256          172.217.3.106:443       ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0    123 192.168.1.2:52030       104.64.74.229:80        ESTABLISHED 18525/cinnamon
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:45554          216.58.219.234:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:34444       138.197.7.47:22         ESTABLISHED 3937/ssh
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:51430          209.85.232.188:5228     ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:41824          216.58.219.237:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome
>
> tcp        0      0 10.8.0.6:45046          92.242.140.21:80        TIME_WAIT   -
>
> udp        0      0 10.8.0.6:45003          172.217.10.238:443      ESTABLISHED 3579/chrome

Some weird ones like:

> tcp        0      0 192.168.1.2:34444       138.1##.7.47:22         ESTABLISHED 3937/ssh
>
> tcp        0    123 192.168.1.2:52030       104.64.74.229:80        ESTABLISHED 18525/cinnamon

Also, when i try to access a website I set up with same iptables rules this appears on client(website is view able on phone)

> tcp        0      1 192.168.1.2:36704       138.197.7.47:80         SYN_SENT    3579/chrome

Could this have anything to do with iptables server rule to accept ESTABLISHED connections? ANY input would be appreciated, usually i figure these little things out by now.

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags  Iface

0.0.0.0         10.8.0.5        128.0.0.0       UG     tun0

0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG     wls1

10.8.0.1        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.255 UGH    tun0

10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH     tun0

128.0.0.0       10.8.0.5        128.0.0.0       UG     tun0

1#8.1#7.7.47    192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH    wls1

16#.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U      wls1

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U      wls1

Sorry about the formatting, I am losing faith in this site but any ideas, even if they are wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely a routing issue at the Ubuntu client. Looks like it's either not actually connected to the VPN, or that it's not the default gateway for outbound traffic.

Comment: traceroute shows client going through vpn, and so does chrome when i ask it for external ip it shows that of VPN machine.